# what will be returned in this method with using statement?

Tags: c#

what this method will return when the `db` is null for some reason? compile is fine and there is no `return` statement outside the `using` block.

```
public Guid GetUserId(string username)
    {

        using (AndeDBEntities db = new AndeDBEntities())
        {
            var userId =
                from u in db.Users
                where u.Username == username
                   && u.Deleted != true
                select new { UserID = u.UserId };
            if (userId == null || userId.Count() == 0) 
                return Guid.Empty;
            else 
                return userId.First().UserID;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `db` is null for some reason, this will likely raise an Exception at runtime.  This will most likely be a [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx), but could be some other exception depending on how it was written.

However, this really shouldn't be possible.  `db` should always be valid, although db.Users may be null if the constructor (AndeDBEntities) doesn't set it properly.  In this case, you'll get a [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx) when you hit your LINQ query (ie: accessing `db.Users`).

Comment: @Reed:  Would the exception hit when accessing db.Users or when calling userId.Count() or userId.First()?  My understanding is, because of deferred execution of LINQ queries, it won't actually execute the query until iterated or accessed.

Comment: @Chris: It'll hit on db.Users, since it's going to need to access it trying to build the expression tree.  It won't actually iterate through the users, but it's still going to hit it...

Answer (score 1):

db will not be null.  If the new allocation fails, an out of memory exception will be thrown and the using block will never be executed, and the function will not return a value (because the exception will blow out of the function too).

Answer (score 0):

Under normal conditions `db` cannot be null.

The only way it can is if the `new` failed, in which case you've got more serious problems.